# Queries regarding Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

if i do not implement or inherit the **monobehaviour** in a class, does that mean i cannot add the components like **Animator, CharaterControler**,etc or use **GetComponent()** to access from the **inspector**?

Comment: if you dont implement monobehavior you cant add it to a game object in the editor, you can refer to components, but it is not one so cannot be found with it.

Comment: of course not... if you dont implement the framework, you cant use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no :)

If you make a class that does NOT inherit from monobehavior, you can still Serialize the class and use this class in another class that DOES inherit from monobehavior.

so if you have a class like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ClassA
{
//you can add and access unity things, for example
public Animator myAnimator;
}
```

then in a class that inherits from monobehavior, you can use your class and see it in the instpector.

```
public class ClassB : MonoBehavior
{
public ClassA myclass; //visible in the inspector.
}
```

You can however NOT use things like "GetComponent", that requires MonoBehavior.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `GetComponent` requires `Component` ;) `MonoBehaviour` inherits from `Behaviour` which inherits `Component`

Comment: So true! Thank you :D